# Is there a faster method to write?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, fs

I made two Codes to make a file and write in it.
The Problem is both are slow (based on Disk Speed)
Is there a better Method to write in a file?

```
let codes = [];
function makeid(length) {
   var result           = '';
   var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
   var charactersLength = characters.length;
   for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
   }
   return result;

};

   for (let i = 0; 1000000 > i; i++)
   {
       codes.push(`${makeid(20)}`);
   }
   fs.writeFile(`./codes/${makeid(5)}.txt`, codes.join('\n'), (err) => {
       if (err)
       {
           message.reply("There was an error processing your request");
           throw err;
       }
   }) 
/* Second Code */
   let stream = fs.createWriteStream(`./codes/${makeid(5)}.txt`);
   for (let i = 0; 1000000 > i; i++)
   {
       stream.write(`${makeid(20)}`);
   }
   stream.end();
   /* Made by Nadelvorhang */
```

Both Codes take 5-15 Seconds.
Im searching a faster Method that could make it in >5sec or instant.
File is saved in a txt.

Comment: Can you add some context to your question? What kind of storage are the files being written to? How long does each method take, and how long were you expecting them to take?

Comment: @TylerMumford so its taking 5-15sec and it should just make txt files with random content in each file and i try to find a >5sec method or instant

Answer (score 2):

**Bottom line**: [Disk access is really slow](https://gist.github.com/hellerbarde/2843375).

If you can create the files in a temporary location ahead of time, moving files is relatively instantaneous. But creating them is slow.

---

Each of the `for` loops in your code writes a 20MB file to the storage device--one million iterations, each one adding 20 characters. In some contexts, 20MB is tiny, and in other contexts, it's HUGE. It's probably not going to be instantaneous on most hardware.

Depending on whether this data is being written to a hard drive or an SSD, performance can vary dramatically. If you're running this program on a device with a hard drive, that's almost certainly the explanation for the bulk of the delay. You can read more on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive#Hard_disk_drives).

But let's try to make it faster.

---

On my machine, I ran your original code at least ten times. Each run took about the same amount of time, give or take 0.2 seconds or so. This is the final timing:

first method: 1168.626ms
second method: 939.847ms
entire program: 2113.624ms

The program didn't actually exit, and the second file didn't actually get written to (flushed), for about 1~2 seconds after the last `console.timeEnd` call. So the two methods are probably more similar in performance than these numbers indicate.

I tried some optimizations that *didn't work*:

1. Extracting `characters` and `charactersLength` to file-level constants
2. Refactoring `makeid`'s `results` to be a `new Array(length)` and then pushing and joining (this was a ~1.8x slowdown, which surprised me)
3. Refactoring `codes` to be a string and using string concatenation (this was a 2x slowdown for the first method)
4. Tidying up the code style (as expected, this had no effect)

...and that's it. I wasn't able to make significant improvements on your code in the 30 minutes I spent trying.

---

Notes and caveats:

1. I'm running directly by running `node` on the command line, not in a web server.
2. I'm running this on a machine with an SSD (PM981 NVMe Samsung 1024GB, according to Device Manager).
3. The first method joins `codes` with newline characters, so it ends up having to write 1-2 MB more than the second method.